# Unable to select specific node's attribute value - XPath

Tags: .net, xml, xpath

XML looks like this:

```
 <Root xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
  <a/>
  <b/>
  <c/>
  <d/>
  <e>Text value</e>
  <f>
   <g>
    <h attr="xyz" />
   </g>
  </f>
 </Root>
```

I'm trying to select the attribute value of the 'h" element. However, I keep getting an error stating that an object reference not set to an instance.

As far as I can tell my XPath query is correct so have no idea what is going wrong. Here's the query I'm using:

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument
doc.Load(document.xml)

x = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Root/f/g/h/@attr").Value
```

Any help is much appreciated!!!

Comment: Where is the exact point in your code that raises that exception?

Comment: When I call SelectSingleNode, once it tries to run that line it throws the exception error.

Comment: That means "doc.SelectSingleNode("/Root/f/g/h/@attr").Value" is not finding the node

Comment: your code with the xml you provided works for me. Are you sure there is no namespace in your xml? What is in `document.xml`?

Comment: I do have namespaces for the Root element, would that matter? I thought that any child elements would automatically inherit the parent's namespaces. So didn't think I would also have to include those in my query.

Comment: Your code works for me with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> namespace in the file.

Comment: Thank you Rene! That was exactly my problem, I didn't bother to include the namespace. Once I threw that in there it worked perfectly. You saved the day!!!